# Pytest pass arbitrary information from test

Tags: python, html, report, pytest

I am writing a python plugin for custom HTML report for pytest test results. I want to store some arbitrary test information (i.o. some python objects...) inside tests, and then when making report I want to reuse this information in the report. So far I have only came with a bit of hackish solution.

I pass `request` object to my test and fill the `request.node._report_sections` part of it with my data.
This object is then passed to `TestReport.sections` attribute, which is available via hook `pytest_runtest_logreport`, from which finally I can generate HTML and  then I remove all my objects from `sections` attribute.

In pseudopythoncode:

```
def test_answer(request):
    a = MyObject("Wooo")
    request.node._report_sections.append(("call","myobj",a))    
    assert False
```

and

```
def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    if report.when=="call":
        #generate html from report.sections content
        #clean report.sections list from MyObject objects
        #(Which by the way contains 2-tuples, i.e. ("myobj",a))
```

Is there a better pytest way to do this?

Comment: Did you get a better solution afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

This way seems OK.
Improvements I can suggest:

Think about using a fixture to create the MyObject object. Then you can place the `request.node._report_sections.append(("call","myobj",a))` inside the fixture, and make it invisible in the test. Like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def a(request):
    a_ = MyObject("Wooo")
    request.node._report_sections.append(("call","myobj",a_))
    return a_

def test_answer(a):
    ...
```

Another idea, which is suitable in case you have this object in *all* of your tests, is to implement one of the hooks `pytest_pycollect_makeitem` or `pytest_pyfunc_call`, and "plant" the object there in the first place.